# Multiple character casing in same TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, casing

How to change character casing in TextBox? I need that 1 line character been Upper and second line character benn Lower

```
isv.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
isv.Text = "Upper"

isv.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Lower;
isv.Text = "Lower"
```

Comment: Your question is quite hard to understand. Could you give a specific example to make it clear? Do you want a multiline text box where characters entered on the first line are automatically uppercased, and characters on the second line are automatically lowercased?

Comment: Which TextBox (Win, WPF, ASP) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark said, it's difficult to understand exactly what you need, but I think it's something like

```
string[] lines = isv.Text.Split('\n');
string finalText = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    finalText += i%2==0 ? lines[i].ToUpper() : lines[i].ToLower() +  + Environment.NewLine;
isv.Text = finalText;
```

Keep in mind I wrote the code without the compiler :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TextBox.Lines` property I guess.

something like:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        result += textBox1.Lines[0].ToUpper() + Environment.NewLine;
        result += textBox1.Lines[1].ToLower();

        textBox1.Text = result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
isv.Text = isv.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine)[0].ToUpper() + isv.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine)[1].ToLower();
```